# Openshift on VCenter UPI installation bootstrap not working

Tags: api, openshift, vcenter

Trying to install openshift in vcenter. The bootstrap is booting up but not grabbing the bootstrap.ign from my web server.

set semanage fcontext public_content_rw_t on /var/www/openshift directory but I am getting

DEBUG Still waiting for the Kubernetes API: Get "https://api.cl.ops.local:6443/version": http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client

my haproxy server looks like this I am only testing with static IP addreses.

```
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Global settings
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
global
    # to have these messages end up in /var/log/haproxy.log you will
    # need to:
    #
    # 1) configure syslog to accept network log events.  This is done
    #    by adding the '-r' option to the SYSLOGD_OPTIONS in
    #    /etc/sysconfig/syslog
    #
    # 2) configure local2 events to go to the /var/log/haproxy.log
    #   file. A line like the following can be added to
    #   /etc/sysconfig/syslog
    #
    #    local2.*                       /var/log/haproxy.log
    #
    log         127.0.0.1 local2

    chroot      /var/lib/haproxy
    pidfile     /var/run/haproxy.pid
    maxconn     4000
    user        haproxy
    group       haproxy
    daemon

    # turn on stats unix socket
    stats socket /var/lib/haproxy/stats

    # utilize system-wide crypto-policies
    #ssl-default-bind-ciphers PROFILE=SYSTEM
    #ssl-default-server-ciphers PROFILE=SYSTEM

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# common defaults that all the 'listen' and 'backend' sections will
# use if not designated in their block
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
defaults
    mode                    http
    log                     global
    option                  dontlognull
    option http-server-close
    option forwardfor       except 127.0.0.0/8
    option                  redispatch
    retries                 3
    timeout http-request    10s
    timeout queue           1m
    timeout connect         10s
    timeout client          1m
    timeout server          1m
    timeout http-keep-alive 10s
    timeout check           10s
    maxconn                 3000

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# main frontend which proxys to the backends
#---------------------------------------------------------------------

listen stats
    bind :9000
    mode http
    stats enable
    stats uri /
    monitor-uri /healthz

frontend api
    bind *:6443
    default_backend api
    mode http

backend api
    balance source
    server bootstrap.cl.ops.local 192.168.61.22:6443 check
#    server master0 192.168.61.23:6443 check
    server master0.cl.ops.local 192.168.61.23:6443 check
    server master1 192.168.61.24:6443 check
    server master2 192.168.61.25:6443 check
    mode http


frontend api-int
    bind *:22623
    default_backend api-int
    mode http

backend api-int
    balance source
    server bootstrap.cl.ops.local 192.168.61.22:22623 check     # Can be removed or commented out after install completes
    server master0.cl.ops.local 192.168.61.23:22623 check
#    server master0 192.168.61.23:22623 check
    server master1 192.168.61.24:22623 check
    server master2 192.168.61.25:22623 check
    mode http



frontend secure
    bind *:443
    default_backend secure
    mode http

backend secure
    balance source
    server worker0 192.168.61.65:443 check
    server worker1 192.168.61.66:443 check
    server worker2 192.168.61.67:443 check
    mode http


frontend insecure
    bind *:80
    default_backend insecure
    mode http

backend insecure
    balance source
    server worker0 192.168.61.65:80 check
    server worker1 192.168.61.66:80 check
    server worker2 192.168.61.67:80 check
    mode h                                                                                                                                                                                                                             14,3          11%
```

Comment: Did you check journal file on your control plane nodes? The message you mentioned  means control plane nodes are still installing. 
If there were issues on your control planes, you could find some errors in the journal file.

Comment: @hiroyukik Thanks for the tip. 

When I pull up the web console in vcenter to look at the control plane ( master0 )

Comment: You need to access to your master nodes with ssh directory. or gather log files using openshift-installer command as following.
`./openshift-install gather bootstrap --dir <installation_directory> --bootstrap <bootstrap_address> --master <master_1_address> --master <master_2_address> --master <master_3_address>" 
`